# Problems with UIImagePNGRepresentation

Tags: uiimage, png, uiimagepngrepresentation

I'm trying to use this line of code

```
 [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

But obviously pngPath is undeclared. So I have to use `stringByAppendingPathComponent`.

I googled examples of this, and I found this

```
myPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
 [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.plist", plistName] ];
[myPlistPath retain]
```

;

The problem is that I don't have a plist file, because I don't need one. How can I solve all these issues and writeToFile the UIImage image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but to get the full path where your file should be saved, you could try this:

```
NSString *file = @"myfile.png";
NSString *directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent: file];
```

and then:

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly my question. The only thing is I get 1 error: Too many arguments to function 'UIImagePNGRepresentation'. Here's my code, it's just was what you gave me.

Comment: NSString *file = @"GameOver Screenshot";
 NSString *directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *path = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
 [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
 return image;

Comment: Yeah, sorry; I copy'n pasted the code in your question. It should be `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`. The second parameter is only there for `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` (it's the quality parameter). Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer if it helped. Thanks.